# Inverses of the operation $(a,b) \mapsto a \oplus b\oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$ for fixed bit length

Tags: hash

**Background.** In their [paper](https://www.aumasson.jp/data/papers/AJN14a.pdf) about the cryptographic scheme NORX, the authors use a fast approximation of + by bitwise operations (taking fewer CPU cycles than proper addition) using the formula $$a+b \; \approx \; a \oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$$ where $\oplus$ is bitwise XOR and $\land$ is bitwise AND, and $\ll$ is left-shift by 1 position.  (The purpose of $((a \land b) \ll 1)$ is to simulate the "carry-bit" operation.)

**Formulation of question.** We can view this as an operation $+^{n}_\sim : \{0,1\}^n\times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}^n$, defined by $(a, b) \mapsto a \oplus b \oplus ((a \land b) \ll 1)$. For $b\in \{0,1\}^n$ we get a map $s^n_b: \{0,1\}^n\to \{0,1\}^n$ defined by $$a \mapsto a +^{n}_\sim b.$$

Is $s^n_b$ injective (and therefore bijective) for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in \{0,1\}^n$?

Comment: That's half-adder. To use it for n-bit you need Full-adder to propagate.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Actually, the $s_b^n$ is not well defined. What does happen to the last carry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to see this note that $a$ can be computed bitwise from the least significant bit. We write $c$ for $a+^n_\sim b$ and $x_i$ for the $i$th bit of $x$. Observe that:
$$a_0=b_0\oplus c_0$$
$$a_i=b_i\oplus c_i\oplus (a_{i-1}\wedge b_{i-1})$$
for $1\le i\le n-1$.

Sadly, there is not a nice 4-bit to 1 bit function bitwise inverse function $(b,c)\mapsto a$ e.g. $a_2$ is a function of $b_0$, $b_1$, $b_2$, $c_0$ and $c_1$.